# I am trying to write a SQL nested query that finds/uses a max value to find the entry just before the max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am fairly new to SQL and am trying to write a query that finds the last time a water meter was read so I can see the value. There is a table of properties that have meters and another table of meters that stores the inputs from engineers. Every input is listed as a sequence, a keyword lists the type of input and expression lists their entry. The max sequence will not always be the answer.

What I am looking for is the last time the read the meter for water and then also get the value for electricity from that reading which is stored in the previous entry (sequence). To make it harder engineers input the sequence number and some go by ones (1,2,3) and others go by twos (2,4,6) so the previous entry may be minus one or maybe minus two.

I can write the queries to find the max sequence and another one to find the entry one previous or two previous but cannot figure out how to make it into one query.

to find the max sequence for site 12345, I have:

```
SELECT MAX(M.SEQUENCE) maxseq  
FROM METERS M JOIN PROPERTY P ON M.PROPNUM = P.PROPNUM  
WHERE (P.CORP_ID ='12345' AND M.KEYWORD = 'WTR')
```

I manually search for the entry before to get the electricity entry with the following query.

```
SELECT  P.NAME, P.CORP_ID, M.KEYWORD, M.SEQUENCE, M.EXPRESSION
FROM METERS M JOIN PROPERTY P ON M.PROPNUM = P.PROPNUM 
WHERE (P.CORP_ID ='12345') 
ORDER BY M.SEQUENCE
```

I have tried different nested queries but have not been able to write anything that will work.

The data that I am interested in for the meters table looks like:

```
PROPNUM   SEQUENCE  KEYWORD EXPRESSION  
10a124    95        ELC     9845
10a124    96        WTR     4521
10a124    97        SVC     A105
10a124    98        HEALTH  GOOD
10a124    99        DAY     150209
10a124    100       HEALTH  GOOD
10a124    101       ELC     10283
10a124    102       WTR     4621
```

I use the property table to find the PROPNUM for the site I am interested as I have the site's ID (CORP_ID) but not its PROPNUM value.

The result I would like to get back would look like below.

```
NAME   WTR_EXPRESSION   ELC_EXPRESSION
SMITH  4621             10283
```

Comment: 1) What database platform? 2) Please show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: Off-hand, windowing queries might be something you should look into.

Comment: Which DBMS? Postgres? Oracle? Btw: don't compare apples to oranges `'12345'` is a character literal, `12345` is a number

Answer (score 1):

You can `inner join` the `METER` table to the `PROPERTY` table once for each `KEYWORD`, and specify that the `SEQUENCE` for `'ELC'` (guessing `KEYWORD`) is less than the `'WTR' SEQUENCE`. Since you are on SQL SERVER, we can do this in a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and `inner join` that data set to the `METER` table to display the `EXPRESSION` values for each `KEYWORD` in a single row:

```
;with wtr_elc as (
    select
        p.PROPNUM,
        p.NAME,
        max(w.SEQUENCE) as max_wtr_seq,
        max(e.SEQUENCE) as max_elc_seq
    from PROPERTY as p
        inner join METERS as w
            on w.PROPNUM = p.PROPNUM
            w.KEYWORD = 'WTR'
        inner join METERS as e
            on e.PROPNUM = p.PROPNUM
            and e.KEYWORD = 'ELC'
            and e.SEQUENCE < w.SEQUENCE
    where  p.CORP_ID ='12345'
    group by
        p.PROPNUM,
        p.NAME)

select
    wtr_elc.NAME,
    wtr.EXPRESSION as WTR_EXPRESSION,
    elc.EXPRESSION as ELC_EXPRESSION
from METERS as wtr
    inner join wtr_elc
        on wtr_elc.PROPNUM = wtr.PROPNUM
        and wtr_elc.max_wtr_seq = wtr.SEQUENCE
    inner join METERS elc
        on wtr_elc.PROPNUM = elc.PROPNUM
        and wtr_elc.max_elc_seq = elc.SEQUENCE
        and elc.KEYWORD = 'ELC'
where wtr.KEYWORD = 'WTR'
```

If you want to do this for more or all `PROPERTY` records, you can modify the `where` clause in the `CTE`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. I get two rows one for electricity and one for water. I had to make one small change to the first inner join. I had to change the w to m and remove the second condition (p.PROPNUM = e.PROPNUM). Is there a way that I can get back just the two expressions for each?

Comment: You mean just the `SEQUENCE` values from the `METERS` table? You can change `select m.*` to `select m.SEQUENCE` or list any columns you want on the `METERS` or `PROPERTY` tables.

Comment: Using your solution, I get my answer in two rows. Is there a way to get them in one row?

Comment: The first query gets the `SEQUENCE` numbers into one row. Do you need any other columns?

Comment: I need EXPRESSION that is associated with each of the SEQUENCE numbers.